# Navbar collapsed icon not responding ONLY on very small screens

Tags: html, navbar, twitter-bootstrap-4

My bootstrap-4 navbar with the "hamburger" in the upper righthand corner of the screen was based on one of the bootstrap examples. **The collapsing and clickable icon both work fine, until the screen becomes very small (i.e. phone size), then it stops responding...**

Observations:

1. Just before it stops working, the menu still appears when clicking just beside the icon, so it seems that some element is sliding on top of the icon as the screen becomes smaller.
2. When I remove `navbar-toggler-right`, the icon moves to the upper lefthand corner and everything works fine...
3. The same behavior occurs on all pages, so it does not seem to be some element outside of the navbar.

**Setting z=999 on the `<button>` works, but it's not very clean...**

The navbar:

```
<nav>
<div class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm transparent navbar-inverse fixed-top" style="position: absolute!important;">
  <button  type="button" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="{{ asset('logo-white.png') }}" width="35" height="35" alt="">
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          etc ... 
        </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Right side (author) -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <!-- Authentication Links -->
    @if (Auth::guest())
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="nav-link">Inloggen</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="nav-link">Registreren</a>
      </li>

    @else
      <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a href="{{ url('/authors') }}/{{ Auth::id() }}" class="nav-link">
          <span class="fa fa-user" style="font-size: 20px;"></span> 
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" class="nav-link" 
            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
            <span class="fa fa-sign-out" style="font-size: 20px;">

           </span>
            </a>

            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
          </li>
              @endif
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please minimize the example code. Also, what is `style="position: absolute!important;"` used for. That's not part of the Bootstrap examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're on an alpha version of Bootstrap, which could be the cause. They recently [released the beta](http://getbootstrap.com/) which should be more stable.

In the latest version they've replaced `navbar-toggleable-*` with `navbar-expand-*`. It looks like they've also removed `navbar-toggler-right`. It should sit on the right by default.